# Grouping JQuery Selections and performing actions on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, query-optimization

I am having an issue with grouping some jquery selections and performing actions on them, they perform as normal when used this way:

```
    $("#divCampLockedState").show();
    $("#divCampLockedState2").show();
    $('#divCampState').show();
    $('#divCampState2').show();
```

But grouping them this way, causes the elements not to show up:

```
    $("#divCampLockedState","#divCampLockedState2",'#divCampState','#divCampState2').show();
```

Similarly, grouping attribute changes from this:

```
$("#CampState_Inactive").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#CampState_Inactive2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to this:

```
    $("#CampState_Inactive","#CampState_Inactive2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

also seems to break things. Is my approach flawed or just improper practice? Thanks!

Comment: Also if you are using jQuery > 1.6 you should be setting disabled through the `.prop()` function.
`$("#CampState_Inactive").prop("disabled", false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following way.

```
$("#divCampLockedState, #divCampLockedState2, ...");
```

`$("#divCampLockedState", "#divCampLockedState2")`: is an alias to `$("#divCampLockedState2").find("#divCampLockedState");`

Answer (score 1):

You group the same way you do in css with a comma, but its still one selector string not multiple

```
$('#divCampLockedState,#divCampLockedState2,#divCampState,#divCampState2').show();
```

etc.

Comment: you should change the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the divs in one quote block

```
$("#divCampLockedState,#divCampLockedState2, #divCampState,#divCampState2").show();
```

Here is the jquery documentation on [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)